# Vertical long text in a multirow

Tags: rotating, multirow, supertabular

I'm finally to finish the transcription of an article in my work, has a long table with a lot of text , for reasons of operating system (debian wheezy) had to be built in an supertabular environment (don't recognize tabularx + xtab). This is an extract of the table that continuous along multiple pages and basically has the same structure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
        \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{supertabular} 
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{array}
  \begin{document}%grumble
        \begin{supertabular}{| c | p{4cm} | p{11cm} |}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Teoría}} & \textbf{Descripción} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}[-3cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE COMPORTAMIENTO}}
         & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text. \\
        \cline{2-3}

        & Teoría sobre recompensas y castigos (líder positivo y líder negativo)(James Burns)  &  Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \cline{2-3}

        & Liderazgo autocrático, participativo(Víctor Vroom y Phillip Yetton) y laissez-faire (Kurt Lewin) & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.  \\
        \cline{2-3} 

        & Teoría del Grid Gerencial (Robert Blake y Jane Mounton) & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \hline

    \multirow{3}{*}[-3cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE CONTINGENCIA}}
         & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text. \\
        \cline{2-3}


        & Long Title & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.  \\
        \cline{2-3} 

        & Long Title & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \hline

\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

My problem is when the cell brakes to continue to the next page the text doesn't and overlaps the bottom of the page. (please note the header do not belong to the table , belongs to the publication's page)

[image]

Comment: you made the same comment in your last question but the fact that you are using debian doesn't stop you using other packages. tabularx is part of the core distribution so you have that already, xtab if you haven't got it you could easily install, or longtable is also part of the core.

Comment: Please fix your example, it gives a missing `\begin{document}` error I added that but now it gives `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` at which point I give up:-) Please make sure the code as posted produces an image that you post.

Answer (score 1):

You never want it to break between the spanned rows so you can set this as a sequence of tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
        \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{supertabular} 
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{array}

\begin{document}%grumble

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

        \begin{tabular}{| c | p{4cm} | p{11cm} |}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Teoría}} & \textbf{Descripción} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}[-1cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE COMPORTAMIENTO}}
         & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text. \\
        \cline{2-3}

        & Teoría sobre recompensas y castigos (líder positivo y líder negativo)(James Burns)   Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \cline{2-3}

        & Liderazgo autocrático, participativo(Víctor Vroom y Phillip Yetton) y laissez-faire (Kurt Lewin)  Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.  \\
        \cline{2-3} 

        & Teoría del Grid Gerencial (Robert Blake y Jane Mounton)  Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \hline

\end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}{| c | p{4cm} | p{11cm} |}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Teoría}} & \textbf{Descripción} \\
        \hline

    \multirow{3}{*}[-1cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ENFOQUES DE CONTINGENCIA}}
         & Text Text Text Text  & A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text. \\
        \cline{2-3}


        & Long Title & Text Text Text Text   A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.  \\
        \cline{2-3} 

        & Long Title & Text Text Text Text   A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text  A lot of Text.\\
        \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought you gave up :P

Comment: @RunarTrollet never believe what you read on the internet